# App crash on Twitter iOS 5.1, when memory warning is simulated.

Tags: iphone, ios5, twitter, objective-c-2.0

```
if ([TWTweetComposeViewController canSendTweet]) {
    // Initialize Tweet Compose View Controller 
TWTweetComposeViewController *vc = [[[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init]autorelease];
    // Settin The Initial Text
    [vc setInitialText:status];

    // Setting a Completing Handler
    [vc setCompletionHandler:^(TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult result) {
        if(result == TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultDone) {
                 NSLog(@"Posted ");
        }
    }];     
} else {
    // Show Alert View When The Application Cannot Send Tweets
    NSString *message = @"The application cannot send a tweet at the moment. This is because it cannot reach Twitter or you don't have a Twitter account associated with this device.";
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Oops" message:message delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
}
```

The code works fine as long as NO memory warning occurs, but as i simulate memory warning on device it crashes the app with the bug.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: 'Cannot remove an observer <TWTweetComposeViewController 0xee2dc80> for the key path "contentSize" from <UITextView 0xee3c5e0> because it is not registered as an observer.'
```

Comment: Are you using ARC? Are you building for iOS5 or iOS6 ? One more problem i can see when you are releasing the vc object ?

Comment: @Praveen-K NOT using ARC and building for iOS 5.0 while device has iOS5.1.1, xCode 4.5.

Comment: Am I wrong or you forgot the presentViewController method?

Comment: Ok fine. Can you please explain me ** [vc setInitialText:status]; ** what it does. Seems like view controller set the text rather than using any text control. What 'status' contains and what happens if it is empty ?